# Is it possible to search a object in an array with both of its properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code

```
const xPosition = coordinates.find(position => position.x === avoidObstacleX);
```

This returns me the coordinates {x: 26, y: 10} this is not wrong, but I have another coordinate that is the one I will like to output which is {x: 26, y: 11} **Is there a way I can pass two parameters to the find method?**

Comment: The *parameter* to  the `find` callback is the element from the array, not the condition variable,  which seems to be a global variable. There is no restriction to use a second global variable in that callback.

Comment: Edited the question to highlight what I believe is the actual question.  Please revise if this possible clarification is not what you desire.

Comment: Do you have the possibility of having duplicate coordinates in your array?  If so, would you like one or all of the matching elements?  Would you like a single object like `{x: 26, y: 11}` returned or an array `[{x: 26, y: 11}]` of all possible matches?  It would help if your question had a sample array such as those in some of the answers allowing us to verify the results. This would better satisfy https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two variables (not parameters to the `find` method itself), like you already use one:

```
function findObstacle(coordinates, avoidObstacleX, avoidObstacleY) {
    return coordinates.find(position => position.x === avoidObstacleX 
                                     && position.y === avoidObstacleY);
}

const xyPosition = findObstacle(coordinates, avoidObstacleX, avoidObstacleY);
```

But from the other answer I now learn that there are two interpretations of your question...

Comment: I like this one. This could also be modified to pass one object and test both properties
`const avoidXY = {
  x: avoidObstacleX,
  y: avoidObstacleY
};

function findObstacle(coordinates, avoidXY) {
  return coordinates.find(position => position.x === avoidXY.x &&
    position.y === avoidXY.y);
}

const xyPosition = findObstacle(coordinates, avoidXY);`

Answer (score 1):

`find` only retrieves a single element, you need to use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
const coordinates = [ {x: 26, y: 10}, {x: 26, y: 11}, {x: 12, y: 34} ]
const avoidObstacleX = 26;

// returns [ {x: 26, y: 10}, {x: 26, y: 11} ]
const xPosition = coordinates.filter(position => position.x === avoidObstacleX);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass one value:

```js
const coordinates= [
  {x: 26, y: 10}, 
  {x: 26, y: 11}, 
  {x: 36, y: 6}, 
  {x: 7,y: 8}
]
const avoidObstacleX=26;
 
let result = coordinates.filter(position=> {
  return position.x === avoidObstacleX  ;
})

console.log(result)
```

You can pass two values:

```js
 const coordinates= [
  {x: 26, y: 11}, 
  {x: 26, y: 11}, 
  {x: 26, y: 11}, 
  {x: 7,y: 8}
]

    function find(avoidObstaclex,avoidObstacley){
    let result= coordinates.filter(position=> {
      return position.x === avoidObstaclex && position.y === avoidObstacley ;
    })

    return result;}
    const avoidObstacleX=26;
    const avoidObstacleY=11;
    console.log(find(avoidObstacleX,avoidObstacleY))
```

Comment: you are not "passing" values, you are using a closure.

Comment: You just need to define it as function and then pass any parameters.

Comment: True, but this is not what you are doing, hence, you are not "passing" values.

Comment: But the accepted answer is not working good. You can try it just gave one value.

Comment: Yeah, the OP is quite misleading. Seems like he only asked about how to filter by different criterias while only selecting a single value as result, so `find` is still the right function to use.